# Javascript - Add authorization header with the shorthand jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the shorthand `$.get` instead of `$.ajax{type : "GET ... }`

Is it possible to define the Authorization header with this shorthand?

Comment: Yes, though it's not going to be so much of a shorthand afterwards

Comment: You can use `$.get` with a full settings object to do this, but then all you save is the `type` property, which is not required for GET requests anyway. The point here is: just use `$.ajax`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I finally changed to $.ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes add the `headers: {}` key. Check [setting](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings) from Jquery official doc.

```
$.get({headers: {}})
```

The offcial doc says:

> A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. All
>   properties except for `url` are optional. A default can be set for any
>   option with `$.ajaxSetup()`. See [`jQuery.ajax( settings )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for a complete
>   list of all settings. The `type` option will automatically be set to
>   `GET`.

Comment: Why when I use : `var get_user_infos = $.get(url, {headers: {"Authorization":window.localStorage.getItem('token')}});` my console say me that I called the API with this query parameter : `headers[Authorization]` ?

Comment: you are doing then something wrong.. can't say without seeing more code